# How to write data to Entity Object

Tags: java, iterator, jtable, transition

I am currently having some issues using the `iterator` in Java. The problem is, the example says I have to write the data given to a Entity Object. The example given is this:

```
setPlayers(iterator.next());
```

That is all they tell me. Where does this method come from? Do I have to create the method? Is it a generated method?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a java collection, say

```
Collection<Player> collection = new LinkedList<Player>();
```

When you want to populate your player list, you can iterate over the collection in multiple ways, one of them being the Iterator approach :

```
Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    setPlayers(iterator.next());
}
```

I have however to inform you that versions of Java after Java 6 provide cleaner ways to iterate :

- `for(Player p : collection) {...` since Java 6 I think
- `collection.stream.forEach(...)` since Java 8

Comment: Ok. I tried this, but it stills says the method is unknown, and that I should create a local method, or i should create a class.